# Oracle SQL - Consulta várias schemas

Tags: sql, oracle

Consegui montar o resultado, faltando agora criar a view com este resultado. Qual a melhor forma?

Esta consulta:

```
"SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',a.OWNER),'.TAB2'),CASE WHEN a.OWNER = UPPER(b.TESTE1) THEN '' ELSE ' UNION ALL' END) TESTE 
FROM ALL_TABLES a LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(b.DB_NAME) TESTE1 FROM INST.TAB1 b ORDER BY b.DB_NAME) b ON a.OWNER = UPPER(b.TESTE1) 
WHERE a.TABLE_NAME = 'TAB2' AND a.OWNER IN(SELECT UPPER(c.DB_NAME) FROM INST.TAB1 c WHERE c.COL2 = 'Y' GROUP BY c.DB_NAME)
ORDER BY a.OWNER"
```

Dá-me este resultado:

```
SELECT * FROM INST1.TAB2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM INST1.TAB2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM INST1.TAB2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM INST1.TAB2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM INST1.TAB2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM INST1.TAB2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM INST1.TAB2
```

E agora, tem como executar este resultado e criar uma view para que fique tanto o resultado como a view permanente? Qual a melhor forma?
Grato.

Comment: O último quadro não tá igual ao segundo?

Comment: O segundo quadro são 3 tabelas, Projeto1, Projeto2, Projeto3.

Comment: Cara, isto esta confuso... qual a relação entre tabela0 e a tabela de projetos? Edite sua pergunta para que ela fique mais concisa.

Comment: Se você quiser montar uma query a partir do resultado da primeira consulta terá que fazer com PL/SQL, usando uma procedure talvez. Na minha opinião a melhor forma de fazer isto é com join.

Comment: uma view com union select coluna1,coluna2... from owner1.tabela1 union select coluna1,coluna2... from owner2.tabela1 ....não sendo isto para ler de forma generica montar a sql e usar um EXECUTE IMMEDIATE mas a questão ficou pouco claro , ao menos para mim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dica: ao invés de `CONCAT(p1,p2)`, utilize o operador de concatenação `||`. Assim:

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' || a.owner || '.TAB2' TESTE
```

Sua primeira operação será agregar todas as linhas em uma só. Você pode fazer isso utilizando `listagg()`. Assim:

```
SELECT   Listagg(teste, ' UNION ALL ') within GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM)
```

O segundo parâmetro de `Listagg` indica o termo a ser inserido entre as linhas concatenadas.

Você pode então utilizar uma variável para acumular o resultado,

```
DECLARE 
  v_cmd VARCHAR2(32767); 
BEGIN 
  SELECT   listagg(TESTE, ' UNION ALL ') within GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) 
  INTO     v_cmd
```

E ao final executar a variável:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_cmd;
```

Sua sequência final ficará assim:

```
DECLARE 
    v_cmd VARCHAR2(32767); 
BEGIN 
    SELECT Listagg(TESTE, ' UNION ALL ') 
             within GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) 
    INTO   v_cmd 
    FROM   (SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' 
                   || a.owner 
                   || '.TAB2' TESTE 
            FROM   all_tables a 
                   left join (SELECT Max(b.db_name) TESTE1 
                              FROM   inst.tab1 b 
                              ORDER  BY b.db_name) b 
                          ON a.owner = Upper(b.teste1) 
            WHERE  a.table_name = 'TAB2' 
                   AND a.owner IN(SELECT Upper(c.db_name) 
                                  FROM   inst.tab1 c 
                                  WHERE  c.col2 = 'Y' 
                                  GROUP  BY c.db_name) 
            ORDER  BY a.owner); 

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_cmd;
END;
```

Comment: Excelente, obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: @Pedro É sempre um prazer ajudar!

Comment: Ao executar dá-me este erro:

'Error report -
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
ORA-06512: at line 4
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.'

Pesquisei e parece que se pode alterar o limite de linhas mas fiquei na duvida de onde e como efetuar essa alteração... qual o procedimento correto para este erro?

Comment: @Pedro me parece que a quantidade de tabelas sofrendo UNION ultrapassa o máximo comprimento oferecido por `LISTAGG`. Neste caso, separe em grupos menores e anexe a v_cmd. Se isto não for possível, utilize um cursor ao invés de LISTAGG para obter as linhas e agregar por iteração.

Comment: usando a mesma estrutura, tem como usar um 'LIMIT', tal como no MySql ou SqlServer, para quebrar de X em X linhas?